# Convert byte array to signed big-endian 16-bit WAV

Tags: python, arrays, audio, pcm

I'm uploading PCM16 audio data from an Android device to a server.

In Java I can do this:

```java
byte[] byteArray = // ...

ByteArrayInputStream baiss = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray);

AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(sampleRate, 16, 1, true, true);
AudioInputStream ais = new AudioInputStream(baiss, format, bytes.size());
AudioSystem.write(ais, AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, new java.io.File(audioFilename));
```

But in **Python**, my audio sounds all garbled up because I cant figure out how to convert the byte array into a signed big-endian 16-bit array.

How can I convert the byte array so I can save it as a WAV file?

Comment: It would really help if you'd show us a small chunk of the data as it's received, by the Python code that you have which you also need to show. Those who have no idea how this data comes from an Android, or don't have a clue on how the Java functions work won't be able to provide any help whatsoever.

Comment: You can use the [buffer_write()](http://pysoundfile.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#soundfile.SoundFile.buffer_write) function from the `soundfile` module to write bytes to a WAV file.

Comment: And BTW, data in a WAV file is little-endian.

Comment: show your python along with any errors